# How can I get the size of a resource without actually downloading it?

Tags: http, curl, network-programming

So I'm on very constrained bandwidth where I am right now and I clicked a link to a pdf tutorial for something and Chrome began to download it and I was watching the size spiral upward from 20Kb past 5Mb and decided to stop it. How do I know it's not a 4Gb pdf?? Ridiculous, I know.

But I started thinking, surely there must be a way I can simply request the size of the resource to check before downloading. Perhaps some sort of cURL request?

Does anyone know a way?

Comment: Use "curl -I" to fetch the HTTP header only.

Comment: Content-Length on the pdf is 0 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the HTTP **HEAD** method.  This should get you the headers of the document without the body.  This *might* have the content length in it.

Or you could send an HTTP Range request header with a **GET** request.  See section 14.35.2 in this [document](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).  Range headers look like:

> Range: 1-20000

which would request the first 20,000 bytes (octets) of a document.  If the document is less than 20,000 bytes, you would get the whole document.

The only problem is that the server might not support the Range header, in which case it will send a 200 status instead of 206.  In that case you can just reset the connection if you don't want to risk burning bandwidth on a 5Gb document.